# gorilla/websocket read tcp i/o timeout in about 1 minutes after connection established

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have run a 'chat' same as the one in the samples, when I have a javascript client connected to the server, it will be disconnected in about 1 minutes, because of 'ReadMessage()' returns an errors 'read tcp 172.29.229.168:8081->172.29.224.1:57917: i/o timeout'.

```
for {
        messageType, message, err := c.RawConn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                c.logger.Errorf("websocket readmessage UnexpectedClose from %s: %v", c.connectionID, err)
            }
            c.logger.Debugf("websocket readmessage closed from %s: %v", c.connectionID, err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", message)
    }
```

Comment: Edit the question to show any code that sets the [read deadline](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetReadDeadline).  The Gorilla examples use ping, pong and read deadlines to detect dead clients.  Did you include that code in your application?